# CodeIgniter Pagination How to add page number as class of every <li></li>

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, pagination

Hi I am working with a app where I get the Codeigniter Pagination through ajax. Problem is on every response, by default Page 1 is selected. 
I am trying to replace the `current` class with `$("#user_pagination ul.pagination li").removeClass("current");` which works fine but problem is to set the `current` class to the current page. I've the variable `index` which has the current page number, now if I had a class with page number like `<li class='2'><a herf="#">2</a></li>`, it would be very easy for me to add the `current` class.

Is there any way to do that using CodeIgniter Pagination class?
This is example of my html

```
<ul class="pagination pagination-sm m-t-none m-b-none">
<li class="current"> <a href="javascript:;">1</a> </li>
<li> <a href="javascript:;">2</a> </li>
<li class="next"><a href="javascript:;"> <i class="" title="Next">»</i></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

If there is any way to select the target `<li>` which has string 2 inside its child `<a>`, and `addClass` to that `<li>`? That would also solve the problem.

Comment: If you using CodeIgniter 2 i can suggest determine current page parameter: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/21898a45f323bb74ef6e5ee8cf21c3397467665b/system/libraries/Pagination.php#L495-L514 i think it will be more right way.

Comment: I know which is my current page, I just want to put the page number in `<li class='2'>` where 2 is my current page now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you right, this code can help you find tag `<li>` which has string `2` inside its child `<a>`:

```
$("#user_pagination ul.pagination li a:contains('2')").parent('li')
```

Comment: This solved my problem :) I used it as `$("#user_pagination ul.pagination li a:contains('"+index+"')").parent().addClass("current");` where `index` variable contain my current page number :)